# Is GoodRelations yet actual or there are other newer alternatives?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, linked-data

I found GoodRelations and thinking about its implementation on some projects.
But i have seen that the last update is on 2011.

**So, my question is: is GoodRelations yet actual or in the meantime are emerged other more valuable and used alternatives?**

The documentation says that it is used by major search engines as Google or Yahoo, but is this still true?

I would avoid a big unuseful work :)

Comment: An interesting question, but not a good fit for Stack Overflow, since "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem  and what has been done so far to solve it."  You might have better luck with this on answers.semanticweb.com .

Comment: But i'm looking for a solution: i have a problem ("Is GoodRelations actual?"). And another one: are there alternatives? I'm not asking for good or bad alternatives, but, generally, for alternatives. I'm not asking for an opinion but just for knowledge o.O

Anyway, thanks for your comment... I'll post to semanticweb.com too...

Comment: As I said, it's not a *bad* question, just not a great fit for *Stack Overflow*.  Questions here should generally have canonical and definite answers.  A list of alternatives is naturally open ended, and whether things are good or not is mostly opinion based.  It's not a *bad* question, just not *Stack Overflow* question.

Comment: The [GoodRelations](http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Main_Page) website says at the bottom, "This page was last modified on 19 December 2013, at 11:13," so it's not quite clear what you mean when you say, "But i have seen that the last update is on 2011."

Comment: Yes, i've seen it, but i downloaded the UML diagram that was updated last on 2011.

Anyway, in the meantime i'm deepening my research and found that GoodRelations were included in Schema.org, so it seems it is yet supported (see here for reference: http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/GoodRelations_and_schema.org).